# Operational Error : unable to open database file (automation)

Tags: python, automation, window, project, operationalerror

**I dont know what I am doing wrong please help me to fix this...**
I am trying to build a telegram bot and with the help of many github researches, I  came up with this code. But I am facing this error please help to solve it.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, connection
import logging
from telethon import sync, TelegramClient, events
import json

with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.loads(f.read())

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)

accounts = config['accounts']

folder_session = 'session/'

for account in accounts:
    api_id = account['api_id']
    api_hash = account['api_hash']
    phone = account['phone']
    print(phone)

    client = TelegramClient(folder_session + phone, api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()
    if client.is_user_authorized():
        print('Login success')
    else:
        print('Login fail')
    client.disconnect()

_________________________________________________________________________________________________*
 

 OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-dd3766aaae79> in <module>
     19         print(phone)
     20 
---> 21         client = TelegramClient(folder_session + phone, api_id, api_hash)
     22         client.start()
     23         if client.is_user_authorized():
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a folder named **session** in the same directory of that Python file.